# jQuery modal dialog is not working

Tags: jquery

I want to have a modal window opened and I've set `modal` to `true` in my code. But it does not work as expected:

```
   $("#fileuploadfun").attr('title',"Upload");
       $("#fileuploadfun").dialog( "option", "modal", true );
```

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: ^ What he said.  Please accept some answers to your previous questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [`.dialog` initialiser syntax](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-modal):

```
$("#fileuploadfun").dialog({ modal: true });
```

According to the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-modal), the syntax you've used there is for setting the modality *after* the dialog has been initialised.

Comment: after setting this property , all the code textfields and combo boxes in that popup are disabled

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to add a modal after the dialog is open, or vice versa.  I ran into the same problem.  It's addressed in this ticket: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6803

This is expected behavior, doing the getter/setter will actually change the option modal if it gets launched again, not while it's open.